# MYSQL IF SELECT COUNT() Is greater that zero select * from table else return nothing found

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, count, where-clause

Am looking for a way to have a query like:

Mysql:

Example: `IF` `SELECT COUNT(column_XX) WHERE column_XX = value_XX`  `FROM table_XX` is greater that zero (`0`) then `SELECT` everything or  `SELECT * FROM` *that* `table_XX WHERE column_XX = value_XX` and *return* all data ... else return *'nothing found'* or just ZERO (`0`)

In simple words,I want to select all the data from a table column if all the values in the column is greater than zero else select only the values>=1 and return all the values.

Which Magic can be applied here to have it done in a **SINGLE QUERY**?... am really Stuck thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by single query,a query without joins?

Comment: Yes with Joints or anything that can work but not like Query1: COUNT then QUERY2: Select in the `PHP` level.... the `COUNT` and `SELECT` should be performed at the `DB` Level i just need the result at the `PHP` Level...Hope it's Clear.. Thanx again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_XX
WHERE column_XX = (
  SELECT column_XX FROM table_XX 
  WHERE column_XX = value_XX GROUP BY column_XX HAVING COUNT(column_XX) > 0
)
```

Comment: SUPER BRAIN!.... Just one thing how would the `IF` and `ELSE` structure be presumed in this TACTIC?

Comment: I mean how will i use the `ELSE` to `return` *zero* `(0)` or *'nothing found'* `if` `count` is `<` `1` at the DB level?

Comment: @UniversalGrasp It will just be empty result set, shouldn't be enough?

Comment: OK.... I Cant agree more.... Thanks a MILLION Times... this has SAVED-ME a huge amount of Googling Hours.... [Accepted Answer]

Answer (score 0):

Would this work !

```
SELECT * FROM test_enum;
+------+-------+----------+
| ID   | Name  | IsActive |
+------+-------+----------+
|    1 | Abdul | No       |
|    1 | Abdul | Yes      |
+------+-------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM test_enum WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test_enum WHERE IsActive = 'No') AND IsActive = 'No';
+------+-------+----------+
| ID   | Name  | IsActive |
+------+-------+----------+
|    1 | Abdul | No       |
+------+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```